# Logout.aspx in Lightswitch 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'd like to know how to use the `logout.aspx` page. I migrated from LS 2012 form authentication and all I need to know is how to make the user able to logout and redirect him again to the login page. I tried to call the `logout.aspx` by creating an empty screen and write this code on the run event:

```
Dispatchers.Main.Invoke(Sub()
                  HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri("LogOut.aspx", UriKind.Relative))
                  End Sub)
```

But it keeps redirecting me to `/Client/LogOut.aspx`. Also when I tried to call the page directly from the browser it gives me error page:

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. To redirect to the `logout.aspx` it must be like this:

```
Dispatchers.Main.Invoke(
    Sub()
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri("../LogOut.aspx", UriKind.Relative))
    End Sub)
```